# How to make create-react-app project hot reload when component in node_module is updated?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I am developing a component and (programmatically) copy its content to `node_module/component` using hard links (I then import component using `import component from "component"`).

Unfortunately, `create-react-app` project is not hot reloaded when `node_module/component` is updated.

Is it possible to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after many experiments, I noticed most changes in `node_module` do trigger a hot reload (hard links should be avoided).

I opened issues on the GitHub repo of [chokidar](https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar/issues/1071) and [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/10475).